# Percent difference in log files

Tags: regex, perl, grep

While going through log files, I often come across the same error message time and time again. Of course, two lines are never identical due to time stamps, usernames, IP addresses, etc.

I'm looking for a way to set a "percent difference", and ignore any lines that are say 90% similar to an already reported error message. Another thought is to *always* ignore time stamp differences too.

Procedure:

1. User inputs search term(s) (either regex or simple text)
2. User inputs tolerance for differences
   [Start]
3. Grep finds string matching search term and sends to new text file
4. Grep continues searching logs, and finds the same error message. Difference might be the time stamp, date, and possibly username. Since the line is at least 90% similar to what's already in the new file, grep doesn't copy it over and continues searching
5. Grep finds new line that matches search term. Line is less than 90% similar, so it gets copied to new file and becomes another line that grep matches future results against.

*Edit: Sorry if I was not clear the first time. I'll gladly explain more if need be.

Thanks.

- Log.1 - DD:MM:YYYY  HH:MM:SS:MS  Error - USER failed to login at IPADDRESS
- Log.1 - DD:MM:YYYY  HH:MM:SS:MS  Hardware failed when booting up
- Log.2 - DD:MM:YYYY  HH:MM:SS:MS  Resources are stretched thin, warning - check RAM

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: What Perl function, or combination of functions would allow me to identify a percentage difference between lines of text. Grep finds an error message and copies to to new file. Grep finds same error message, but different time stamp. Since error message is at least 90% similar, ignores it and moves on. Repeat, repeat, repeat.

Comment: @r.misc: you should edit your question to add further information and explain what it is you want.

Comment: Can you post sample lines, format or if there are specific points where differences should be ignored (first x characters, next x characters after some identifier, etc)?

Comment: @mhitza: The time stamps are usually in the exact same place, but the user names are not. These are not CSVs, nor separated by a certain delimiter every time.

Comment: @r.misc I wasn´t assuming something of that manner, but more so in the style of an Apache/Postfix log file where while different entries may go in they all have a standardized format around which you can build parsers/analyzers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any full out-of-the-box solutions but [Text::Levenshtein](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Levenshtein/Levenshtein.pm) and similiar algorithms can help you come up with how similiar one generic string is to another.

Comment: That looks pretty similar to what I'm searching for, I only fear it is not robust enough. And it would be nice if I didn't have to download extra mods. How might I implement something similar with the default packages?

Comment: You could write the levenshtein algorithm yourself. Its not terribly complicated. See the wikipedia artice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: If that's the closest thing to an out-of-the-box solution to comparing lines of text, I'll take it. I don't mind writing a few extra lines to keep it all non-third party.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to cache your log messages with a timestamp, so you don't repeat a message you've seen in the last, say, minute.

```
my %msg_cache = ();
sub log_filter {
    my $msg = shift;
    if (defined($msg_cache{$msg}) && $msg_cache{$msg} < time-60) {
        # we've logged this message in the last minute - skip
        return;
    }
    $msg_cache{$msg} = time;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: That's a neat idea too. Something else I was considering, would be to grab the 3-5 lines before and after each unique error message. This way, we could see what may have led to the message.